# После сборки приложения в jar , не находится файл, хотя при запуске приложения из Idea все работает

Tags: java, ssl

Ошибка: class path resource [keystore/afinny.p12] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/keystore/afinny.p12
Ниже прикладываю yml и код, из которого вызываются настройки.

public class FeignConfig {

```
@Value(value = "${server.ssl.key-store}")
Resource keyStore = null;
@Value(value = "${server.ssl.key-store}")
Resource trustStore = null;

@Bean
public Encoder multipartFormEncoder(@Autowired RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(new ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters>() {
        @Override
        public HttpMessageConverters getObject() throws BeansException {
            return new HttpMessageConverters(restTemplate.getMessageConverters());
        }
    }));
}

@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
            .create()
            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore.getFile(), "password".toCharArray(), "password".toCharArray())
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getFile(), "password".toCharArray())
            .build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
            .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory =
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код в виде текста, а не картинкой.

Comment: Добавил, спасибо)

Comment: А сам ключ сгенерирован? Есть в наличие?

Comment: ключи это файл https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate (тут описание как он генерируется) соответственно у меня файл лежит в ресурсах, но когда все собирается в jar, почему то приложение перестает находить этот файл.